# How to call variable value inside string in PHP

Tags: php

How do I call my PHP initialized variable inside the string of `onclick=""` ?
I have Initialized `$counter=7` and want to use that counter inside `onclick=""` function.
This is how I did which is not working.

```
<a class="blogpost page-transition" href="the_permalink();" onclick="gotoPageWithTrans6($counter)">
```

I also Tried doing this, but the following code also didn't worked.

```
<a class="blogpost page-transition" href="the_permalink();" onclick="gotoPageWithTrans6(?php $counter ?> )">
```

Any solution ?

Comment: <?php echo $counter ?>

Answer (score 2):

You are only missing the echo statement:

```
a class="blogpost page-transition" href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>" onclick="gotoPageWithTrans6(<?php echo $counter ?> )
```

Comment: It wasn't just a missing echo statement - the OP was missing an opening angle bracket for the second PHP tag. Also, [`the_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink) does its own output, so this specifically does not need an echo.

Comment: I was needing just echo, this made my work done and for the opening angle bracket it was skipped by Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Cleaner `short_open_tag` version with correct onclick attribute:

```
<a class="blogpost page-transition" href="<?=the_permalink()?>" onclick="gotoPageWithTrans6(<?=$counter?>)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo at `<?PHP` start tag.it should be

```
onclick="gotoPageWithTrans6(<?php echo $counter; ?> )"
```

or

```
//php short tags enabled
onclick="gotoPageWithTrans6(<?= $counter ?> )"
```

instead of

```
onclick="gotoPageWithTrans6(?php $counter ?> )"
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and easy?

```
onClick="gotoPageWithTrans6(<?= $counter ?>)"
```

The short `PHP` tag allow you to easily output the values of PHP variables right inside your HTML code.